# Local Development using MAMP, Tomcat, Java

Tags: java, macos, git, tomcat, mamp

My current organization is building their web application using java. I don't want to start using Eclipse. I'm the front-end web guy--HTML & CSS specifically. We're using GIT as version control. I need to be able to make a CSS change, save my file locally, and see the effect of that change (either through auto-refresh using something like LiveReload, or manual refresh).

In my previous company we used PHP, so MAMP + Live Reload worked fine. Because I'm in a java environment now, that setup doesn't quite work.

I've installed Tomcat into MAMP so that when I launch MAMP I also launch tomcat at localhost:8080. However, I don't know what else I need to do, in order to actually view the local version of the application (which is cloned to my hard drive using GIT clone). My co-workers are similarly clueless, as they all use Eclipse for their IDE, which handles all of this for them.

Help!

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm kind of late to the party here, but I hope this will be helpful for you still.

Java web applications are often packaged as WAR files or some other type of package. When you deploy this into Tomcat, it expands the archive. If you go to the Tomcat directory (Assuming you used a guide earlier, this is probably something like /Applications/MAMP/tomcat or /Applications/MAMP/bin/tomcat) there should be a 'webapps' directory. Open that, and inside you should find a directory for each web application.

In these web application directories is a 'resources' directory. The CSS and images are usually found here. The HTML is usually found in the web application directory. This allows you to make a change immediately and view it, for rapid UI development. HOWEVER! This change is occurring outside of the GIT repository, so although you can view it immediately it is not making the change in a place where you can save it. When you are happy with the result, you will need to copy these files over to the correct places in the GIT repository.

Still, this is a method I use to make rapid UI changes and see my results without waiting for it to compile, or having to boot up Eclipse if I'm only doing UI.

You could make this simpler as well by going into terminal and using: 'ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tomcat/webapps/ ~/Webapps' This will create a link to the Tomcat WebApps directory in your Home directory, so there's no need for you to track it down each time.

Answer (score 0):

If they use Eclipse for everything - including building - you currently do not have much choice besides using Eclipse yourself.

The crucial step is to automate the building of what goes in Tomcat.  You can get the ball rolling by saying that "Our organization needs a Continuous Integration server", because for that to work you need your projects to be buildable outside Eclipse. Maven is good for that, and you can run maven locally on your own computer to make your life easier (and even run Tomcat directly on the files without redeploying after each change).

There is a *lot* of benefits to Continuous Integration servers, this just being one of them.  You boss might find it a very valuable addition to your development team.